# Should I sync my desktop and documents via OneDrive?

Tags: sync, onedrive

With windows 8.1 there's now the option of moving these 2 folders to a web synced one drive folder.

Will this allow me to sync my appdata and settings on any windows device I own?

Or is this a disaster in the making?

Does windows 8.1 by default synchronize everything in the roaming folder with my other devices? Or is this only when I'm connected to a network?

Answer (score 0):

*> With windows 8.1 there's now the option of moving these 2 folders to a web synced one drive folder.*

Not only is this a feature in 8.1, this is a feature you can utilize in any desktop OS that OneDrive can be installed on.

*> Will this allow me to sync my appdata and settings on any windows device I own?*

The [OneDrive tip](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/onedrive-upgrade-desktop-app) suggests you can move your Desktop or Documents location to be under the OneDrive folder to allow syncing of the contents.

As an option, you can [sync portable applications](http://portableapps.com/) using OneDrive. This is okay because all the application files reside inside one folder.

[image]

*> Does windows 8.1 by default synchronize everything in the roaming folder with my other devices? Or is this only when I'm connected to a network?*

Microsoft has a detailed explanation on online-only files vs files being available offline:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/onedrive-online-available-offline